# How do I access the Sequelize model inside of the Trails model

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, trailsjs

I am trying to get https://github.com/jarrodconnolly/sequelize-slugify to work within my Trails setup, but I can't see a way of accessing the Model that is created by Sequelize inside of the Trails model. The plugin example says I need to do something like:

```
SequelizeSlugify.slugifyModel(SequelizeModelHere, {
    source: ['title'],
    suffixSource: ['year']
});
```

I noticed that trails creates a Sequelize model and adds it to the service locator under `this.app.orm[model.globalId]`, I however can't access this inside of the Trails model itself as it would not have been created by then. I wanted to do this all inside of the model itself, but if there is no way of doing this, I will do it in a Service instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right, currently there no way of doing it under the model itself because they are just the definition used to create the sequelize models.

What you can do is use trailpack-bootstrap to initialized them after everything is setup.

You should also create an issue under trailpack-sequelize to raise this limitation, I think it can be good to have such possibility and shouldn't be too hard to add :)